# Eliminar elementos según criterio

Tags: android, android-studio, clase, botón

estoy creando un juego donde se crean círculos de diferentes tamaños y colores cada cierto tiempo. El problema es que quiero eliminar todos los círculos de un color al tocar un botón. Por ejemplo tengo el botón rojo y tiene que eliminar todos los círculos de color rojo pero no logro hacerlo.

Alguno tiene alguna idea para orientarme? Gracias.

Clase Juego:

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView{

Bolitas bolitas;
Paint paint;
int i = 0;

private List<Bolitas> sprites = new ArrayList<Bolitas>();

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
    sumarBolas();
    sprites = new ArrayList<>();

    bolitas = new Bolitas(this);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    for (Bolitas bolitas : sprites) {
        bolitas.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    invalidate();
}

private Bolitas createSprite() {
    return new Bolitas(this);
}

public void sumarBolas(){
    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (i<5){
                sprites.add(createSprite());
                i++;
                sumarBolas();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Clase Bolitas:

```
public class Bolitas {

Juego juego;
Paint paint;
int color, donde_aparece, velocidadX=5, velocidadY=5, x, y, radio;
boolean una_vez = true;

public Bolitas(Juego juego){

    this.juego = juego;

    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (una_vez == true) {
        Random random = new Random();
        color = random.nextInt(4);
        radio = random.nextInt(70) + 30;
        donde_aparece = random.nextInt(4);

        if (donde_aparece == 0) {
            x = random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
            y = radio;
        } else if (donde_aparece == 1) {
            x = random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
            y = canvas.getHeight() - radio;
        } else if (donde_aparece == 2) {
            y = random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
            x = radio;
        } else if (donde_aparece == 3) {
            y = random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
            x = canvas.getWidth() - radio;
        }
        una_vez = false;
    }

    if (color == 0) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
    } else if (color == 1) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
    } else if (color == 2) {
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
    } else if (color == 3) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
    }

    if (x >= canvas.getWidth() - radio) {
        velocidadX = -5;
    }
    if (x <= radio) {
        velocidadX = 5;
    }
    if (y >= canvas.getHeight() - radio) {
        velocidadY = -5;
    }
    if (y <= radio) {
        velocidadY = 5;
    }

    x = x + velocidadX;
    y = y + velocidadY;
}
```

}

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button rojo;
Juego juego;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rojo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rojo);
    juego = (Juego) findViewById(R.id.juego);
}

public void rojo(View view){

}
```

}

Comment: Hola Zekirak, porque no indicas como las piensas eliminar?, me hiciste recordar una certificación que tomé, donde tenía que mostrar bolitas que crecian, flotaban y las pinchabas al tocar, ¿es similar o aporta más detalles.?

Comment: Lo que estaba pensando era agregarle un identificador a cada circulo que se crea para saber de que color es cada circulo y con diferentes botones ir eliminando los círculos que correspondan (el botón rojo elimina a todos los círculos de color rojo). Estuve probando pero nada de lo que hago funciona.